# Why does Visual Studio start when opening a WindowsApplication.exe file?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, debugging, visual-studio-2012

I have a VStudio2012 solution for a Windows form app that has been compiled and runs fine for me when I launch it from myproject\bin\debug\utility.exe (the mainform comes up fine and the program runs fine).

I am trying to get a colleague familiar with the program and when he creates a shortcut to the above program and opens the utility.exe by doubleclicking it, then VStudio comes up instead of the mainform of the app.

Is there any way to achieve this without getting into some deployment scenario? I would like to leave this utility.exe where it is now and just get somebody else to run it from there? Is this possible?

Comment: Your friend is opening the .config file, not the .exe. See "hide  extensions for known file types".

Comment: Great idea...that could be it. He is not a developer and he may have the extensions hidden for his logon session. I will followup with him and see.

Comment: If he's not a developer, why is VS installed on his machine??

Comment: @Chris - it is my development machine which I gave him a logon to do a bit of testing of this windows app (we are a very, very small company). Did you downvote this question?

Comment: @HighCore - Your premise was correct. This "end-user" colleague of mine was describing to me on the phone that he clicked on the .EXE when in fact he did not have the file extension exposed and he was opening the CONFIG file. We are remote from each other and not sharing screens. I want to give you proper credit for the answer so please post a short answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your friend is opening the .config file, not the .exe.

See "hide extensions for known file types"